# Как организовать быстрый Reverse Routing?

Tags: php

Есть такой роутинг

```
'/' => ['site', 'index'],
'/[s:action]' => ['site', '{action}'],
'/[s:controller]/[s:action]' => ['{controller}', '{action}'],
'/[s:module]/[s:controller]/[i:id]' => [ '{controller}', 'view', '{module}'], //$id - параметр передаётся в action
'/[s:module]/[s:controller]/[s:action]/[i:id]' => ['{controller}', '{action}', '{module}'], //$id - параметр передаётся в action
```

Как направить URL на нужные Controller и Action понятно.
Но теперь проблема с тем чтоб проанализировать обратные URL. И чтоб эта реализация не использовала много ресурсов, так как скорее всего будет вызываться для генерации множества ссылок на страницах.

Допустим нужно сформировать ссылки для примера:

```
 '/' => '/',
 'site/index' => '/',
 'site/login' => '/login',
 'user/info' => '/user/info'
 'user/profile/view/123' => '/user/profile/123',
 'user/profile/edit/123' => '/user/profile/edit/123',
```

**примеры**

Допустим мы вводим URL **/** и попадаем на контроллер **site** экнен **index**, теперь на основе этого же правила нужно сделать обратное правила для redirect/rewriterule/reverseroute/alias как еще назвать не знаю. 
То есть нужно чтоб при вводе URL **/site/index** мы попадали на **/**

Допустим мы вводим URL **/user/profile/123** попадаем в модуль **user** на контроллер **profile** экнен **view** с параметром **id**=123, 
Аналогично из правил роутинга нужно чтоб при вводе URL **/user/profile/view/123** нас редиректило на **/user/profile/123**

И т.д. По правилам роутинга описанным выше

**Попробую еще раз**

1. Пользователь вводит URL **/**
2. Роутинг срабатывает на первом правиле(`'/' => ['site', 'index']`), и вызывается `SiteController::index()`
3. Всё отлично и хорошо.
4. Возможна другая ситуация, пользователь вводит URL **site/index**
5. Роутинг срабатывает на третьем правиле(`'/[s:controller]/[s:action]' => ['{controller}', '{action}']`), и также вызывает `SiteController::index()`
6. Потом приходит СЕОшник, и говорит, а почему у нас два URL отдают один и тот же контент, это не комильфо. Сделай переадресацию на основную страницу, тоесть на **/**, и так для всех правил описанных в роутинге.
7. Задаю вопрос на StackOverflow, как это сделать имея правила роутинга описанные выше. 
   `'/' => ['site', 'index'] ====> '/site/index' => '/'`

**Немного про формат роутинга на всякий случай**

Ключ - это условие по которому обрабатывается URL

- **s:** - string
- **i:** - integer

Значение - это массив состоящий из

- controller
- action
- module

В явной форме или в виде {placeholder}, который берётся из URL по маске в ключе

Comment: Не понятно, что значит "обратные URL" ? Сформировать наиболее короткий урл для текущих MCA ?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, в текущем виде не очень-то и ясно что и куда переделать.

Comment: @Other, В вопросе есть ряд входных и выходных данных, также описал это всё же словами.

Comment: @Гончаров Александр, не уловил что значит аббревиатура MCA?

Comment: Хотел ответить... А оказалось, что действительно непонятно...

Comment: @Qwertiy. Что именно не понятно?

Comment: @Ninazu, вообще, что надо сделать. Сначала хотел ответить про то, как по url получить параметры. Потом посмотрел вопрос и подумал, что по контроллеру, экшену и параметрам надо получить url. Потом посмотрел внимательнее и понял, что вообще не понимаю, почему в примерах говорится о преобразовании одного url  в другой.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что и так?

Comment: Ну тут либо убирать третье правило - CEO-шник счастлив, те немногие, кто вводил полностью - нет. Либо в самом начале обработки отслеживать такие пути и редиректить посредством windows.location на "/", а дальше по стандартному сценарию

Comment: @Ninazu, теперь понятно. Но переадревация в данном случае - это не очень хорошо, по-моему. Возможно, следует `link` использовать. В любом случае, вопрос тот же, а как ответить я теперь не очень знаю.

Comment: А через .htaccess это нельзя сделать?

Comment: @zhenyab, Будем считать что в этой ситуации нет. Нужно именно PHP реализация ибо вся логика PHP роутинга теряется.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то есть дефолтный module/controller/action или еще что то там И если, к примеру, action дефолтный, то он в урле быть не должен. Но если, к примеру, controller дефолтный, но action не дефолтный, то controller выкинуть не получится. Вроде в приведенный пример вписывается.

Comment: @Skywave - в роутинге есть явные экшены, а есть динамические. Обновил вопрос для еще большей ясности.

Comment: @Ninazu Что вы конкретно спрашиваете? Вам нужен алгоритм или примеры реализации ? Какая реализация у вас уже есть?

Comment: @Ninazu MCA это module+controller+action - ветка роутинга

Answer (score 1):

То есть перечитав я усёк - у тебя несколько роутов ведут на один и тот же MCA (module controller action). Ты же хочешь, чтобы всегда оставалось только одно соответсвие URL <=> MCA - например чтобы редиректило, или выдавало 404. Добавлю ещё одно определение - роут, это шаблон(может быть строкой, массивом, коллбеком, и вообще чем угодно), по которому определённые URL адреса можно распарсить в MCA + массив параметров.

Делается так - роутам добавляется параметр priority , или он может по умолчанию высчитываться от строковой длинны роута, например. Далее после этапа бутстрапа приложения - отсортируй роуты по priority.

Предположим что для роутера ты завёл класс `SomeRouter`. Этот класс должен иметь как минимум два метода: parse (собрать MCA из URL-строки, может вернуть false - если URL не подходит ни единому роуту) и stringify (собрать MCA+прочие параметры в URL-строку). Этот класс содержит роуты (список, который в вопросе под фразой "Есть такой роутинг")

Так вот при парсинге роута должен быть код, суть которого примерно:

```
$requestMCA = SomeRouter::parse($URL);
if (($goodURL = SomeRouter::stringify($requestMCA))!=$URL){
    return redirect($goodURL);
}
```

Главная суть этого - как парсинг URL, так и сброрка URL - **должны работать согласно предсказуемым приоритетам роутов** : по приоретам работают циклы сбора/разбора внутри `SomeRouter`.  При первом хите цикл сборки/разборки прерывается и возвращается результат.

**UPD**:
Обычно более конкретные роуты имеют более высокий приоритет, а менее конкретные - более низкий приоритет. Например роут `/` - наивысший приоритет, а роут `/[s:module]/[s:controller]/[s:action]/*` - низший приоритет.

Comment: Вот как раз суть вопроса это метод stringify, MCAP, я распарсил

Comment: @Ninazu код сборки зависит от системы роутинга. В твоей системе роутинга - не хватает приоритетов. И параметризация непонятна - не пойму смысл правой части роута, не пойму - есть ли указания обязательные/необязательные параметры. Так то - в любом фреймворке есть сборка, но в ZF2 например в классе каждого роута разные методы сборки - потому что роуты могут быть заданы по-разному. Твои роуты похожи на `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment` - советую посмотреть код метода `buildPath`. Но там определение роута более широкое.

Comment: В моём случае массив роутов уже отсортирован от большего к меньшему

Comment: @Ninazu, ок. Вы уж извините, но алгоритм построения урла по MCA писать не буду - это олимпиадная задачка 9й класс) А в общем концепцию - описал вам.